# cannot insert null value into the table Orders

Tags: c#, sql

i am having a problem regarding inserting records to my database, 
the error says: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'OrderNo', table 'Receipt.dbo.Orders'; column does not allow nulls. Insert Fails. then the statement has been terminated", but when i checked my codes, i cannot seem to find any error. Can somebody help me? Thank you in advance:

Here is my set of codes:

-for save sales order-

```
private void SaveSalesOrder(string status)

        {                
            int nOrder = 0;

            CloseConnection();  

            OpenConnection();

            trnOrder = cn.BeginTransaction();

            SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand();

            try
            {
                cmdInsert.Connection = cn;
                cmdInsert.Transaction = trnOrder;
                cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmdInsert.CommandText =
                    "INSERT INTO Orders " +
                    "(OrderDate, CustomerNo, CustomerName, CustomerAddress, PurchaseOrderNo, AgentName, Status) " +
                    "VALUES ('" +
                    dtpOrderDate.Value.Date.ToString() + "', '" +
                    txtCustomerNo.Text + "', '" +
                    txtCustomerName.Text + "', '" +
                    txtCustomerAddress.Text + "', '" +
                    txtPONo.Text + "', '" +
                    cboAgentName.Text + "', '" +
                    status + "'); " +
                    "SELECT TOP 1 OrderNo FROM Orders " +
                    "ORDER BY OrderNo DESC;";

                nOrder = Convert.ToInt16(cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

                for (int nRow = 0;
                    nRow <= dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].Rows.Count - 1;
                    nRow++) 
                {                      

                    double dQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["Quantity"].ToString());

                    string strUnit = dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["Unit"].ToString();

                    int nProductNo = Convert.ToInt16(dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["ProductNo"].ToString());

                    string strProductName = dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["ProductName"].ToString();

                    string strProductSize = dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["ProductSize"].ToString();

                    string strPackagingInside = dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["PackagingInside"].ToString();

                    double dSellingDiscount = Convert.ToDouble(dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["SellingDiscount"].ToString());

                    double dSellingPrice = Convert.ToDouble(dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["SellingPrice"].ToString());

                    double nAmount = Convert.ToDouble(dsDetail.Tables["OrderDetails"].
                        Rows[nRow]["Amount"].ToString());

                    SqlCommand cmdInsertDetail = new SqlCommand();

                    cmdInsertDetail.Connection = cn;
                    cmdInsertDetail.Transaction = trnOrder;
                    cmdInsertDetail.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmdInsertDetail.CommandText =
                        "INSERT INTO OrderDetails " +
                        "(OrderNo, PackagingOutside, Quantity, Unit, ProductNo, ProductName, " +
                        "ProductSize, PackagingInside, SellingDiscount, SellingPrice, Amount) " +
                        "VALUES ('" +
                        nOrder + "', '" +
                        dPackagingOutside + "', '" +
                        dQuantity + "', '" +
                        strUnit + "', '" +
                        nProductNo + "', '" +
                        strProductName + "', '" +
                        strProductSize + "', '" +
                        strPackagingInside + "', '" +
                        dSellingDiscount + "', '" +
                        dSellingPrice + "', '" +
                        nAmount + "')";

                    cmdInsertDetail.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

                trnOrder.Commit();

                if (status == "OK")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Transaction has been saved!", "Success",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Transaction has been voided!", "Void Transaction",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                trnOrder.Rollback(); 
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            finally
            {
                cn.Close();
            }
        } 

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (txtCustomerNo.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a customer first.", "Empty", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            btnSearchCustomer.Focus();
            return;
        }

        if (grdDetails.Rows.Count < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a product first.", "Empty",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            btnProductSearch.Focus();
            return;
        }

        SaveSalesOrder("OK");

        groupCustomer(false);
        groupProduct(false);
        CSalesInv.EnableDisable(this, false);

        CloseConnection();

        InitializeOrder();

        lblTotal.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the design of your Orders table ? Chances are its set to not allowing nulls

Comment: Try to insert null value in the DB manually.Check its primary key!!

Comment: You probably want to change your `OrderNo` column to have an Identity relationship (if it's Microsoft SQL Server), or be `auto_increment` if it's MySQL

Comment: Please please please please research "sql injection" and "parameters"

Comment: yes, the OrderNo is in primary key that is why it is set to not allowing nulls

Comment: @user2627130 it sounds like you just want to make the PK into an `IDENTITY` column

Comment: `nOrder = Convert.ToInt16(cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString());` Can you once check the value of `nOrder` in this particular line ??

Comment: Even if `nOrder` is Pkey no way you can get a `NUll` value for `nOrder` variable. If you get Null value for `cmd.Insert.ExecuteScalar().Tostring()` Tostring can not handle null values and you will get error there. if we use `Convert.Tostring` it will handle Null values and it will return nOrder as `0` not Null still. If `OrderNo` is primary key and auto incremented,Than just do not include it in your query and everything is fine.

Comment: Well i think you are trying to get last inserted `OrderNo` from Orders table and want to define this `OrderNo` as Unique key for `OrderDetails` table , now if you can show us the schema of your order details and please check what value you are getting for `OrderNo` .

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated from the database.  The OrderNo column in your database is set to not allow NULL.  I presume you wanted some sort of unique ID, but ticked the "No NULLs" instead.

What database are you using?

Comment: What vendor?  MySQL, Oracle, Microsoft?

Comment: `nOrder = Convert.ToInt16(cmdInsert.ExecuteScalar().ToString());`  nOrder can not give Null value i think.

Answer (score 0):

You're not specifying OrderNo in your query. Unless this is an `IDENTITY` field it will not autoincrement for you.

You can do two things:

- Check the databse and ensure `OrderId` is set to allow nulls
- Make Orderid an identity column.

You probably want to use `SQL Parameterized queries` also to prevent SQL Injection.

```
 cmdInsertDetail.CommandText = "INSERT INTO YourTable (CustomerNumber) VALUES (@CustomerNo)";

 cmdInsertDetail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerNo", txtCustomerNo.Text);
```

This will also be more efficient than building up a random `SQL` string.

Answer (score 0):

One really cool idea is that you can return the identity number to let you know that the row has been added on which row number. Yes, Order Number need to be set to allow nulls in the table if you want that there is missing order number in some cases.

https://qualitybusinessintelligence.com/Code/ASPDOTNET/Insert-Into-Multiple-Tables.pdf

Here I am adding the identity number (OrderID) to a label for output to be returned, which tell's me what row it is on when the row is added: (Just trying to help)

```
         [CODE]
         "', " + " '" + emp.SignedName +
         "', " + " '" + emp.SignedDate + "') SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); ");
         [/CODE]
```